# Django project not writing to file

Tags: python, django

Am trying to append a file in Django to do a string replace for some reason its not writing to the file. Am having no problems reading.

views.py

```
with open('/home/me/dev/Django/rulebase/result.rb', 'a') as discover_reading:
    mydiscover = File(discover_reading)
    for line in mydiscover:
        line.replace('input = "', 'this')
    mydiscover.closed
```

I get this error on my browser:

```
Exception Type:     IOError
Exception Value:    

File not open for reading
```

Comment: Well, `open(..., 'a')` opens for writing (appending), not reading. However, your code doesn't make a lot of sense. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Are you trying to copy contents of a file to another file `mydiscover ` replacing some of the content?

Comment: I want the code to open a file search for the string and then replace string in the file.

Comment: You can replace a sequence of bytes, but you can not change the length of the replaced sequence. Write a new file instead.

Answer (score 1):

The following will replace the contents of the file:

```
with open('/home/me/dev/Django/rulebase/result.rb', 'r') as discover_reading:
    lines = [line.replace('input = "', 'this') for line in discover_reading.readlines()]

with open('/home/me/dev/Django/rulebase/result.rb', 'w') as discover_reading:
    discover_reading.writelines(lines)
```

You're example does not work *at all*.

Read the docs for [file objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) and [string.replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) please. `File` is not a builtin function, `str.replace` does not replace in-place (strings are immutable) and the `mydiscover.closed` is for telling whether or not the file is closed, *not* for closing an open file.

Your original error was raised because you are attempting to read lines from a file you've opened with the `a` flag which stands for append.

Comment: Thank you at the end of it want I it do is to remove that entire line add then replace it with 'this'. It does take remove the unwanted characters after that. When i run the script the file contains

`input = "Default"`

When I run the script it gives me 

`thisDefault"`

Comment: @saiyan101 Yeah, that's the behavior for `string.replace(to_replace, replace_with)`. Each occurrence of `to_replace` is replaced with `replace_with`. If you want to replace the contents *after* `input = "'`, you'll need to use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You must open it using 'r' flag, for reading.

```
open('/home/me/dev/Django/rulebase/result.rb', 'r')
```